# Cannot access 3-D Schrödinger eigenfunctions from NDEigensystem

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

The following solves the first 3 eigenvalues of the following simple 3D-Schrödinger equation, but I do not know how to use the interpolating eigenfunctions, i.e., 
`funs[[2]][0,0,0]` does not return a value. This does not happen in 2-Dimensions.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Rcube = ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] <= 1 && Abs[y] <= 1 && Abs[z] <= 1, {x, y, z}]; 
F[x_, y_, z_] := If[x + y + z <= -2, 0, 1]; 
{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + F[x, y, z]*u[x, y, z],
                              DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]}, u[x, y, z], 
                             Element[{x, y, z}, Rcube], 3]
```

Comment: The problem is that you had set `NDEigensystem[]` to return objects of the form `ifun[x, y, z]` instead of `ifun`, where `ifun` is an `InterpolatingFunction[]`. Try `{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + Boole[x + y + z > -2] u[x, y, z], DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]}, u, {x, y, z} ∈ Rcube, 3]` and then `funs[[2]][0, 0, 0]`. (Note the second argument I gave!)